# Should I use server side render only the login page in Reactjs?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

My team is developing SPA using MySQL, .net(server) & React, Is it OK to provide login from React or it will be good to do login from server side and the rest of the app still client side. 
I follow the client side login via API + auto redirect to login page if user is not authenticated but my friend is insisting on the server way.

What is the pros and cons of each method? Which should I use in this project.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication should really be controlled by the server.

Having it client side allows for possible security vulnerabilities.
When you say authentication client side, do you mean the React app will perform a SQL query itself?

The best practice for having the same authentication across multiple apps/services is to have one central API control the authentication process and then each each app/service call that API.

Comment: I mean client will login via API(sending username+password) . And then server will respond with cookies or tokens.

Comment: My friend wants to use the server to render the login page as well but I don't understand why we have to do that

Comment: Can't see any particular positives or negatives to either. Having the login page rendered by the server could offer consistency to the user. Login methods such as Facebook go down the server rendered method but that's likely so they can place tracking cookies outside of their normal control.